# How can I temporarily disable StyleCop on my machine?

Tags: stylecop

I'm being 'forced' to use StyleCop on an external project but I find it very invasive to my style of working as it interrupts the flow of my work making progression very slow. I'm having to document everything before I'm even close to finishing it. I'm even being forced by StyleCop to write valid documentation for code I know I'm going to delete or refactor in half an hour once I've run it once or twice in order to test something.

How can I temporarily turn it off so I can get on with my work?

(I can re-enable it and sort out any documentation and formatting issues before I commit my source to source control)

Answer (score 1):

How is this "forcing" being accomplished?  Even if StyleCop is being invoked via MSBuild at compile-time and its warnings are being treated as errors, it's quite possible that it's being executed after compilation, in which case your assembly is presumably already available, and nothing is truly blocked.

If it is being run via MSBuild, regardless of whether it's triggered before or after the compiler, the simplest fix would be for the solution owner to provide a build configuration (e.g.: "Debug Compile Only") in which all forms of static analysis, including StyleCop, is omitted.  It is quite likely that you are not the only developer for whom the integrated analysis is at least occasionally an inconvenience, and an extra build config is the "polite" way to address this.

Comment: Good point. I'm not sure if it can be disabled by a build configuation as it's seemingly all controlled by a StyleCop.settings file within each project. I have found out I can disable it by adding this file but I don't want to accidentally commit this file with this change. A "testing" build would be better so I will investigate...

Comment: If there's no build integration, what is making StyleCop run in the first place?

Comment: A a Visual Studio plugin I think.

Comment: The StyleCop addin for Visual Studio does not run automatically.  You need to trigger each analysis manually from the UI.  If you're not doing this, something else is triggering its execution.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question:

This is non optimal but it can be disabled by editing the StyleCop.settings file (which is in each project in my solution):

```
<StyleCopSettings Version="105">
    <GlobalSettings>
      <BooleanProperty Name="RulesEnabledByDefault">False</BooleanProperty>
    </GlobalSettings>
</StyleCopSettings>
```

I'd prefer to just have a build setting somewhere than editing the actual file, but I guess this will have to do unless anyone knows a better way?  It's a shame StyleCop itself doesn't have a UI button to turn it on and off.

Comment: Agh. For some reason this setting is no longer being honoured by stylecop